# Windows Phone 7.1 Advertising Sdk on Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build my wp7 project under vs2012 express for wp. It uses the ad sdk, but I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   7   The name "AdControl" does not exist in the namespace 
    "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=
    Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI".
```

Does anyone know why?

CLARIFICATION - i'm not trying to upgrade my project to wp8 at this time --- just trying to build for 7.1 like before using the new sdk.

Should I be also installing the old 7.1 phone sdk?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Thanks

Comment: are you missing a using statement?

Comment: it compiled file with the wp7.1 sdk...

Comment: @swinefeaster - if it compiled fine what exactly is your question?

Comment: cause it did not compile file in vs2012 for wp express, see above error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem - deleting the Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI reference from the project and readding it and a reference to Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile fixed it for me.

Comment: yes you were right, just an outdate reference. i found that there was one already installed (likely with the Windows Phone 8 sdk) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Advertising for Phone\Libraries\v7.1

Answer (score 0):

you can check on the following things:

1. Check whether you updated the target phone framework to "Windows Phone 8.0 OS"
2. check if you can see yellow exclamation icon in Advertising SDK dll in references folder in Solution Explorer. if yes, then delete that reference and add the reference again to advertising sdk dll from "Add Reference" dialog box.

Comment: thanks but i'm not trying to upgrade the app to wp8 --- i'm just trying to build it using the new sdk...

Comment: @swinefeaster - The new sdk only support Windows Phone 8.  The Windows Phone 7 SDK has not been released to support Windows Phone 7.8 ( no information on 7.8 has been released ).

Comment: i'm not trying to target 7.8 --- i'm targeting 7.1 as the original question indicates